# Strange behavior with Arrays and slice

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with some arrays in JavaScript when I came across something strange.  Here is my code:

```
var origArray = new Array("one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight");

var newArray = origArray.slice(1,3);
origArray[1] = "octopus";
console.log(newArray.join()); //prints two,three 

var origArray = new Array(["one","two"],["three","four"],["five","six"],["seven","eight"]);

var newArray = origArray.slice(1,3);
origArray[1][0] = "octopus";
console.log(newArray.join()); //prints octopus,four,five,six
```

I don't understand why `newArray` gets affected in the second case and not the first.  What's going on here?

Comment: Slice makes a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a distinction between *shallow copying* and *deep copying*.

`slice` result is another object than the original, but it does not mean that objects *within array* (all the way down) were duplicated. If those inner objects happen to be arrays, *they* are shared between the copy and the original.

Comment: So, the only time this happens is when the original array's elements are also arrays?

Comment: @SethenMaleno: Arrays or any other objects. This is because what's being copied is a *reference* to the object, not the object. With primitives (strings, numbers, booleans), the actual primitive is copied. (Well, effectively. Primitive strings -- strings in general -- are a special case it's best not to go into here...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay, so if it's an Array or Object, it's referenced, but if it's just a primitive value like a Number, String or Boolean it's just copied.  Is that correct?

Comment: @SethenMaleno: Effectively, yeah. It's exactly the same as `var a = []; var b = a; b.push(1); console.log(a.length);` which displays `1` because `a` and `b` refer to the same array. Or `var a = {}; a.foo = "afoo"; var b = a; b.foo = "bfoo"; console.log(a.foo);` which logs `"bfoo"` because `a` and `b` refer to the same object. But `var a = 5; b = a; b = 6; console.log(a);` logs `5` because we changed the *contents* of `b`, not the state of the thing it refers to.

Comment: @SethenMaleno: Last example: `var a = {}; a.foo = "afoo"; var b = a; b = {}; b.foo = "bfoo"; console.log(a.foo);` That logs `"afoo"` because we assigned a new value to `b`, so at that point `a` and `b` weren't pointing to the same object anymore.

Comment: @SethenMaleno: The key thing here is what the value held by a variable is (and the "variable" in question can be a property in an object, such as an element in an array). In the case of objects, the value held is a reference to the object, not the actual object. In the case of primitives, it is (effectively) the actual primitive. (Really done now. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for explaining that to me man, it makes a lot of sense the way you laid it out.  I really appreciate all of the examples!!  You're the coolest!

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays are references then, *slice* copy the references and not the values.